# Displaying the message in the div in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have created a form which includes the following field and below it I have created a div with the id email_feedback to display the message.

```
label>Email</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input name="email" id="email_id" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
    <div id="email_feedback"></div>
</div>
```

and I have created the following jquery function in a separate file in js.

```
$(function() {       
  $("#register_submit").click(function() {
     $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/login_register/about", 
            { email : $("#email_id").val() }, function(data) {
        $("#email_feedback").html(data);
        console.log(data.length);
     });
  });
});
```

and I have written the following function in the controller.

```
function about() {     
  $email = $this->input->post('email');
  $email_verify = $this->userdata_insertion->read_user_information($email);
  if($email_verify == "true"){
     echo "The user already exists";
  }
}
```

and this function in the model.

```
public function read_user_information($email) {

  $condition = "email =" . "'" . $email . "'";
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('vtiger_users_details');
  $this->db->where($condition);
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
     return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

but whenever I try to use the email id that I have used before it is not showing the error message can anyone let me know where I am committing the mistake.

Comment: what is `console.log(data.length);` giving??

Comment: did you try `vardump($email_verify);` in your `function about` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the **base URL** whenever I use to pass the base_url in the jquery as follows.

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/login_register/about
```

it uses to consider the path of the controller where the function is been written and then concatenate the base URL to that resulting in the wrong URL. I have removed the echo "base_url()" and it is working fine now.

Comment: BTW what in your config setting for `base_url `?

Answer (score 0):

try :

Controller:

```
if($email_verify){
echo "The user already exists";
}
```

Model:

```
public function read_user_information($email) {


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vtiger_users_details');
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

     if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
        }
   }
```